# reset the vertical scrollbar so that it starts always at the top

Tags: angular, primeng

Hello everyone I am using prime ng in angular. I was using p-tabview and found that when I am switching to the tabs the scrollbar remains at the same position. I want to reset the position of the scrollbar to the top

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: window.scrollTo(0,0);
on click of that p-tabview, you can call a function and just use this, or in the tabswitch function you can use this

Comment: tried that before but nothing happened. Should i use @viewchild to access the element apply the .scroll method?

Answer (score 0):

If this tab change implies a new route you can use the following:

```
@NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            routes,
            {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'}
        )],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
```

Comment: I am not routing to any page I am just using ng if to render the components. So whenever we r clicking on a tab a component is rendered